# Is there a (pure) CSS operator that would merge class declarations?

Tags: html, css

When I'm making my CSS file, I have this:

```
input[type="text"],
input[type="email"],
input[type="password"],
input[type="number"],
button{
   padding:10px
   border-radius:10px;
}

input[type="text"],
input[type="email"],
input[type="password"],
input[type="number"],
button,
.shadow{
    box-shadow: ....
}
```

Can I somehow merge these 2 declarations in pure CSS so I would, instead, have something like this:

```
input[type="text"],
input[type="email"],
input[type="password"],
input[type="number"],
button{
   padding:10px
   border-radius:10px;
}
+ // some operator that would join the next class declaration on the previous declaration
.shadow{
    box-shadow: ....
}
```

By "pure" on the title, I mean is it possible to do this without LESS or SASS?

Comment: There isn't, but if you're using a CSS preprocessor, this feature is pretty trivial :)

Comment: There isn't yet, but there's a draft of a spec that aims to support this, [here](https://tabatkins.github.io/specs/css-nesting/).

Answer (score 0):

It is not Possible without LESS or SASS or SCSS.

With SCSS you can try something like this.

SCSS

```
.shadow{
  box-shadow:1px 1px 1px solid red;
}

input[type="text"],
input[type="email"],
input[type="password"],
input[type="number"],
button{
   padding:10px;
   border-radius:10px;
   @extend .shadow;
}
```

Hope this helps..

Answer (score 0):

There isn't but if you simply write this...

```
input[type="text"],
input[type="email"],
input[type="password"],
input[type="number"],
button{
   padding:10px
   border-radius:10px;
}
.shadow{
    box-shadow: ....
}
```

...the defined box-shadow will be added to the according input elements which  have the `shadow` class, and all their other properties are kept too.